How to make the mapping rules in red hat 3Scale, if they are not sent automatically, they are loaded as empty and sent to the backend
Good morning, I am currently starting to work with Red Hat 3Scale and I am making an api that has the following GET request with QueryParam:
/UDB/v1/UDB?ISDN={ISDN}&IMSI={IMSI}&CONTENT={CONTENT}

What happens is that my backend is capable of receiving OR type requests with the QueryParam, so it is not always necessary to send all the parameters, but in this case 3Scale requires me to always send the 3 parameters to take the route as validate , otherwise it indicates that you do not get it:
Query the Backend

Consult the product in 3Scale:

Is there a solution for this or is it necessary to add all possible query cases by QueryParam manually in the mappingRules?
